# How to output NLTK pos_tag in the string instead of a list?

Tags: python, list, nltk, pos-tagger

I need to run nltk.pos_tag on a large dataset and need to have its output like the one that is offered by Stanford tagger.

For example while running the following code I have;

```
import nltk
text=nltk.word_tokenize("We are going out.Just you and me.")
print nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

the output is: 
[('We', 'PRP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('going', 'VBG'), ('out.Just', 'IN'), ('you', 'PRP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('.', '.')]

In the case that I need it to be like:

```
 We/PRP are/VBP going/VBG out.Just/NN you/PRP and/CC me/PRP ./.
```

I prefer to not using string functions and need a dirrect output because the amount of the text is so high and it adds lots of time complexities to the processing

Comment: Why would a string function be any slower than an NLTK method for doing the same thing?

Comment: Because I don't believe that NLTK (or Textblob)  developers create list and then change it (inefficient!), but they could have created POS in the text directly.

Comment: Using `/` to concat the word and pos causes complications. What happens if you have `he / she` in your text you would get `he/PN /// she/PN`, then parsing the string output would be a mess.

Comment: Also, I think you're overthinking about using string functions to concat the strings, it's really not that expensive. =)

Comment: I don't want to use: list= (nltk.pos_tag(text))
str1=(''.join(str(e) for e in list)).replace('\'','').replace(', ','_').replace(')(',' ').replace('(','').replace(')','')....I'm going to try this code but I looking for more beautiful one!

Comment: The string replacements you suggested would end up with more complications, e.g. you won't be able to get back your original string easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short:**

```
' '.join([word + '/' + pos for word, pos in tagged_sent]
```

**In long:**

I think you're overthinking about using string functions to concat the strings, it's really not that expensive.

```
import time
from nltk.corpus import brown

tagged_corpus = brown.tagged_sents()

start = time.time()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for i, sent in enumerate(tagged_corpus):
        print(' '.join([word + '/' + pos for word, pos in sent]), end='\n', file=fout)

end = time.time() - start
print (i, end)
```

It took 2.955 seconds on my laptop for all 57339 sentences from the brown corpus.

[out]:

```
$ head -n1 output.txt 
The/AT Fulton/NP-TL County/NN-TL Grand/JJ-TL Jury/NN-TL said/VBD Friday/NR an/AT investigation/NN of/IN Atlanta's/NP$ recent/JJ primary/NN election/NN produced/VBD ``/`` no/AT evidence/NN ''/'' that/CS any/DTI irregularities/NNS took/VBD place/NN ./.
```

But using string to concatenate the word and POS can cause trouble later on when you need to read your tagged output, e.g.

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> tagged_sent = pos_tag('cat / dog'.split())
>>> tagged_sent_str = ' '.join([word + '/' + pos for word, pos in tagged_sent])
>>> tagged_sent_str
'cat/NN //CD dog/NN'
>>> [tuple(wordpos.split('/')) for wordpos in tagged_sent_str.split()]
[('cat', 'NN'), ('', '', 'CD'), ('dog', 'NN')]
```

If you want to saved the tagged output and then read it later, it's better to use `pickle` to save the tagged_output, e.g.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> tagged_sent = pos_tag('cat / dog'.split())
>>> with open('tagged_sent.pkl', 'wb') as fout:
...     pickle.dump(tagged_sent, fout)
... 
>>> tagged_sent = None
>>> tagged_sent
>>> with open('tagged_sent.pkl', 'rb') as fin:
...     tagged_sent = pickle.load(fin)
... 
>>> tagged_sent
[('cat', 'NN'), ('/', 'CD'), ('dog', 'NN')]
```