# How to save the output into a file in python?

Tags: python

I have code as:

```
handle = open('abc.txt','r')
tokens = []
sys.stdout=open("test.txt","w")
for line in handle:
    tokens+=word_tokenize(line)
print(tokens)
sys.stdout.close()
```

When I try to run it, it takes very long time (more than 40 mins) in my computer, but takes only few seconds if not to save in a file. In what way the code can be changed so the output is written to a file at minimum time?

Comment: You print your contents _many times_. Each loop iteration prints all previously collected tokens. Move `print(tokens)` out of the loop by unindenting it.

Comment: Use `pickle`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865623/how-to-output-nltk-pos-tag-in-the-string-instead-of-a-list

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for something like this:

```
from itertools import chain
with open('abc.txt') as infile:
    tokens = list(chain(*map(word_tokenize, infile)))
with open("test.txt","w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(tokens))
```

Your tokens will be saved one token per line.